# Rails 3: DataMapper instead of ActiveRecord

Tags: orm, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, datamapper, adapter

After all the hussle about *Rails 3*, can I, after all, painlessly use *DataMapper* without almost changing my *ActiveRecord* code so that I could run my *Rails* at *GAE* without any bother?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you still have to add the properties for DataMapper, and a bunch of code in the gems you are using might not be ORM-agnostic. And you have to change your queries to the DM syntax (which is IMO more beautiful than the AR one), or you can use some of the old AR ones by using the gem dm-ar-finders. And what's GAE?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Everything seems so tiring, when one needs to rewrite code with similar functionality. By GAE I ment Google Apps Engine. I actually succeeded in making my app work on it (using some kind of Java version of Ruby, probably was called JRuby), but then, GAE provides only DataMapper support, and it means some amount of rewritting code, too.

Comment: Well, have fun with DataMapper, Query Objects and `find(:name.like => "Albus")` ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I am a bit exhausted from all this mess, but fun there will be – Soon or later!